# No override function in ValueTransformer?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, binding, nsvaluetransformer

Since my last question I went on trying to make a ValueTransformer transform the values of a NSSlider into Integer.

Background:
I have an NSSlider which is bound to Shared User Defaults Controller. A textlabel is also bound to the Shared User Defaults Controller with the same key. I need the textfield to only show Int.

Now my code looks like this:

```
class IntegerTransformmer: ValueTransformer {

    override class func transformedValueClass() -> AnyClass {
        return NSNumber.self
    }

    override class func allowsReverseTransformation() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    // as far as I know, here is an override function required. But doing override in the following line, i´m getting error.
      func transformedValue(value: Any?) -> Int? {
        let int = value as! Int
        return int
    }
}
```

For both, NSSlider and the label I set in bindingsInspector the the Value Transformer on `IntegerTransformmer`.

In AppDelegate I initialize the ValueTransformer like this:

```
 override class func initialize() {
        let newTransformer = IntegerTransformmer()
        ValueTransformer.setValueTransformer(newTransformer, forName: NSValueTransformerName(rawValue: "IntegerTransformmer"))

    }
```

The building works without error, but in my label, I´m still getting DoubleValues.
Why I´m not allowed to make `transformedValue(value: Any?)`as override?
Is this the reason why it´s not working?
Help of any kind would be much appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't look like you are overriding the abstract class method, have you tried using code completion? You should have an override method that looks like  `override func transformedValue(_ value: Any?) -> Any?`

Comment: Have you had a look at ``NSNumberFormatter``? This is probably more appropriate than a value transformer in this situation.

Comment: @ Paul: Is it possible to use a NSNumberFormatter for a textfield which gets it´s value from Shared User Defaults Controller?

Comment: @ Dennis: thats the solution, what a relief! Big, big thank you!

Comment: @ Paul: Would still be interested if I could use a value from Shared User Defaults Controller in combination with NSNumberFormatter. Thanks to you too.

Comment: Get an ``NSNumberFormatter`` instance from Interface Builder's *Object Library*, drop it onto your text field, customise it accordingly, then see if it does what you want it to when your program runs.

Comment: @ Paul: Thank you for such a basic, but unbelievable useful advice!!